# MyCanvas.Children[i] -> Change background

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to loop through the elements of my canvas to change their backgrounds.

```
myCanvas.Children[i]. ???
```

but I only can edit things like the opacity... Any Idea how I can do it?

```
for (int j = 0; j < myCanvas.Children.Count; j++)
            {
                 if(Random == 0 && Canvas.GetTop(myCanvas.Children[j]) >= 499 && Canvas.GetLeft(myCanvas.Children[j]) == 0 )
                {
                        myCanvas.Children[j].

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Children` here is a `UIElementCollection` but `UIElement` does not have any `Background` property. You have to cast it to such as `Control` so that the `Background` property can be accessed. Or you can also try using the `SetValue` method like this:

```
myCanvas.Children[j].SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```